# zsh function case condition parse error near `)'

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I'm following this blog to setup a zsh function to switch aws cli profiles
: https://mads-hartmann.com/2017/04/27/multiple-aws-profiles.html

This is the zsh function in the blog:

```
function aws-switch() {
    case ${1} in
        "")
        clear)
            export AWS_PROFILE=""
            ;;
        *)
            export AWS_PROFILE="${1}"
            ;;
    esac
}

#compdef aws-switch
#description Switch the AWS profile

_aws-switch() {

    local -a aws_profiles

    aws_profiles=$( \
        grep '\[profile' ~/.aws/config \
        | awk '{sub(/]/, "", $2); print $2}' \
        | while read -r profile; do echo -n "$profile "; done \
    )

    _arguments \
        ':Aws profile:($(echo ${aws_profiles}) clear)'
}

_aws-switch "$@"
```

I added these lines to my ~/.zshrc, when I run source ~/.zshrc
It gives /.zshrc:4: parse error near `)'
I read the zsh function doc but still not very good at understanding the syntax and how could I fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the zsh man page (`man zshmisc`):

*case word in [ [(] pattern [ | pattern ] ... ) list (;;|;&|;|) ] ... esac*

As you see, you have to separate multiple pattern by `|`:

```
case $1 in
  |clear)
    ....
```

Comment: For C-like fall through, you can also use `"") : ;&`, which executes the no-op `:` and terminates the case with `;&`, which causes the next block to be execute as well as if it matched `$1`.

Comment: so where exactly should I put this | at? I tried to put infront of clear like in your suggestion and many other positions, but none of them worked.

Comment: Post your complete modified code. It should work. I tried it out with my Zsh, version 5.5.1.